# How can i close a while loop , on a quiz i am making after 10 questions have been answered?

Tags: python, random, while-loop

```
while True:
    if play.lower() == "yes":
        print("great, here we go!")

        first = random.randint(1, 10)
        second = random.randint(1, 20)

        questionA=input("what is" + str(first) + "+" + str(second))

        userAnswer = first + second

        if userAnswer == userAnswer:
            print("well done")


    elif play.lower() == "no":
        print("ok goodbye")
```

Comment: "break" is what you need, used to exit a loop

Comment: Or you can have a counter and change the condition in the `while` loop to smth like: `while counter is not 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using some sort of a variable that keeps the track of number of questions. For eg: In the code snippet below, the `noOfQuestions` is checked if it is equal to or less than 10, if yes then your while loop gets executed else not.

**Code:**

```
noOfQuestions = 1
while noOfQuestions<=10: #<-- check if noOfQuestions is less than or equal to 10
    print noOfQuestions
    noOfQuestions += 1 #<--- update the noOfQuestions variable
else:
    print ("noOfQuestions is %d.")%noOfQuestions
```